# How to make http call when using Authentication Guards in Angular2

Tags: angular2-services

I am using authentication guards in my project. while i call http service i am getting invalid response / Anonymous object, Instead of the actual data.

below is my module.ts file

```
    // providers used to create fake backend
   import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
   import { HttpModule,JsonpModule }    from '@angular/http';
   import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
   // used to create fake backend
   import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/index';
   import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
   import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

   import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
   import { routing }        from './app.routing';

   import { AlertComponent } from './_directives/index';
   import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
   import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService, AdminService }                      
   from './_services/index';
   import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
   import { AdminDashComponent } from './home/admindashboard.component';
   import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
   import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
   import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           BrowserModule,
           FormsModule,
           HttpModule,
           routing  ,
           ChartsModule,
           JsonpModule  
       ],
       declarations: [
           AppComponent,
           AlertComponent,
           HomeComponent,
           LoginComponent,
           RegisterComponent,
           AdminDashComponent
       ],
       providers: [
           AuthGuard,
           AlertService,
           AuthenticationService,
           UserService,  

           fakeBackendProvider,
           MockBackend,
           BaseRequestOptions,
           AdminService
       ],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })

   export class AppModule { }
```

this is my Angular service

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

   @Injectable()
   export class AdminService {

     // Define the routes we are going to interact with
     private dataUrl = 'app/_services/admin.json';

     constructor(private http: Http) { }

       adminData:any;

     // Implement a method to get the public deals
      getData(){

         var jwt = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
         var authHeader = new Headers();

         if(jwt) {
           authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);     
         }

         this.http.get('app/_services/admin.json', {headers: authHeader})
                   .map(res => res.text())
                   .subscribe(
                    data => {console.log('before assign ', data);
                    this.adminData = data;
                        console.log('after assign ', this.adminData)
                    },
                    err => console.log(err),
                   () => console.log('Complete')
     );
         console.log('at the end' , this.adminData);
         return this.adminData;
       }

   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you don't wait for http.get() and return adminData before it's set up. You should use ReplaySubject like this

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    adminData: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

    // Implement a method to get the public deals
    getData(){
        var jwt = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        var authHeader = new Headers();

        if(jwt) {
            authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);     
        }

        // if first request get data from backend otherwise from cache
        if (!this.user.observers.length) {
            this.http.get('app/_services/admin.json', {headers: authHeader})
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('before assign ', data);
                this.adminData.next(data);
                console.log('after assign ', this.adminData)
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Complete'));
        }

        console.log('at the end' , this.adminData);
        return this.adminData;
    }
}
```

In that case you return observable, subscribe in your component and when request to backend done you get your real data

Comment: Thanks! i tried this,still my response is like this ReplaySubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false…}

Comment: I am expecting this as response Response {
  headers: Headers
  ok: false
  status: 401
  statusText: "OK"
  type: 2
  url: "..."
  _body: ""
}